# CheckBox List item not posting in mvc 5

Tags: checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making an attendance panel for the students that are enrolled in the particular batch. For that I'm displaying the records of the students along with the number of checkboxes according to the number of classes assigned for that batch. Everything is displayed correctly, However checkboxes of only one row carry values to the post, and rest of the checkboxes in other rows are not posted. The student details for each row is posting correcting in a list.

Below is my code

**StudentAttendance.cs**

```
public class StudentAttendance
    {
        public List<Models.User> userlist { get; set; }
        public List<Models.Days> days { get; set; }
    }
```

**InstructorController.cs**

```
public ActionResult AssignedStudents(string id)
        {
            Models.StudentAttendance viewmodel = new Models.StudentAttendance();
            //viewmodel.studentbatch = new Models.StudentBatch();
            //viewmodel.user = new Models.User();

            Context.Instructor instructor = new Context.Instructor();

            viewmodel.userlist = new List<Models.User>();
            viewmodel.days = new List<Models.Days>();
            viewmodel.userlist = instructor.lstAssignedStudents(id);

            Context.Batches contBatch = new Context.Batches();
            var days = contBatch.SelectDays(id);
            int totaldays = contBatch.CalculateDays(days);

            var duration = contBatch.GetallBatchList().Where(p => p.Id == id);
            var batchduration = (from c in duration where c.Id == id select c.Duration).ToList();
            string d = batchduration[0].ToString();

            int totalduration = contBatch.GetBatchDuration(d);

            int TotalCheckBoxes = totalduration * totaldays;

            List<string> getdays = contBatch.getdaysinList(days, totalduration);
            List<Models.Days> day = new List<Models.Days>();

            for (int i = 0; i < TotalCheckBoxes; i++)
            {
                day.Add(new Models.Days { dayid = i, dayname = getdays[i], ischecked = false });

            }

            viewmodel.days = day;

            return View(viewmodel);
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MarkAttendance(Models.StudentAttendance viewmodel)
        {
            Models.StudentAttendance viewmodel1 = new Models.StudentAttendance();
            //viewmodel.studentbatch = new Models.StudentBatch();
            //viewmodel.user = new Models.User();
            return View();
        }
```

**AssignedStudents.cshtml**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.StudentAttendance

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AssignedStudents";
}

<h2>AssignedStudents</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MarkAttendance","Instructor", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>@Html.DisplayName("First Name")</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayName("Last Name")</th>
    </tr>

@for (int j = 0; j < Model.userlist.Count; j++)
{

    <tr>
        <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.userlist[j].Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.userlist[j].FirstName)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.userlist[j].LastName)</td>  
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.days.Count; i++)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.days[i].ischecked)
                @Model.days[i].dayname
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.days[i].dayid)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.days[i].dayname)
            </td>
        } 
    </tr>  
 }
</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" id="Attendance" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>


}
```

Comment: Your just creating duplicate checkboxes, with duplicate `name` attributes (and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html). The `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first matching name. Its not clear what you want to achieve. Should each `User` have a collection of `Days`? (in which case your model is wrong)

Comment: Yes, each user have a collection of days.

Comment: Then you need a view model for a User (Student?) which contains a collection property for the Days and then use nested `for` loops

Comment: That didn't help either. Defining a property of class days in a list also posts only one row of checkbox values.

Comment: Then you did not do it correctly!

Comment: Let me edit my question.

Comment: There is some odd code in your GET method. Are your `User` and `Day` classes data models or view models?

Comment: Both of them are data models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161573/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user100020).

Comment: StudentAttendance is a view model that contains both the user and day as a data model

Comment: The issue is with ids which are generating for control. 

1. if loop is repeating for First User then it generates id of Days as days_1__dayname for hidden field.
Same when loop repate for second user then it  generates id of Days as days_1__dayname for hidden field.

That's why it is getting only one row data.

Comment: There is a slight confusion, can you come to chat again?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue using viewmodel as a List in the controller class.

**StudentAttendance.cs**

```
List<DayVM> days = new List<DayVM>
{
    new DayVM(),
    new DayVM()
};

List<StudentVM> model = new List<StudentVM>
{
    new StudentVM{ Id = 1, FirstName = "Bob", Days = days },
    new StudentVM{ Id = 2, FirstName = "john", Days = days },
}
return View(model);
```

and inside view

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    ... elements for properties of Student
    @for(int j = 0; j < Model[i].Days.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Days[j].IsSelected)
        ....
    }
}
```

and taking List for collecting values in the post action

```
public ActionResult MarkAttendance(List<Models.StudentVM> lst)
{
.....
}
```

All thanks to Stephen Muecke who made it easy.